# How to search through multiple (thousands) of JSON files to find files with a specific value and then append those specific values to a new list

Tags: python, json, search

I recently generated 10,000 images with a corresponding .json file. I generated 10 before I did the bigger collection and so I am trying to filter out or search through the 10,000 json files, for a specific key value. here is one of the JSON files for example:

```
{
  "name": "GrapeGrannys #1",
  "description": "Grannys with grapes etc.",
  "image": "ipfs://NewUriToReplace/1.png",
  "dna": "93596679f006e3a9226700e0e7539179b532bf29",
  "edition": 1,
  "date": 1667406230920,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Backgrounds",
      "value": "sunrise_beach"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "main",
      "value": "GrapeGranny"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "eyeColor",
      "value": "gray"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "skirtAndTieColor",
      "value": "green"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Headwear",
      "value": "hat1"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "specialItems",
      "value": "ThugLife"
    }
  ],
  "compiler": "HashLips Art Engine"
}
```

In "attributes", I want to I want to target the first object and its value and check to see if that value is equal to "GrapeCity".
Then after all files have been read and searched through, Id like the files with that specific value "GrapeCity" to be stored in a new list or array that I can print and see which specific files contain that keyword. Here is what I have tried in Python:

```
import json
import glob
# from datetime import datetime

src = "./Assets/json"

# date = datetime.now()
data = []


files = glob.glob('$./Assets/json/*', recursive=True)



for single_file in files:
  with open(single_file, 'r') as f:

    try:
      json_file = json.load(f)
      data.append([
        json_file["attributes"]["values"]["GrapeCity"]
      ])
    except KeyError:
      print(f'Skipping {single_file}')

data.sort()

print(data)


# csv_filename = f'{str(date)}.csv'
# with open(csv_filename, "w", newline="") as f:
#     writer = csv.writer(f)
#     writer.writerows(data)

# print("Updated CSV")
```

At one point I was getting a typeError but now it is just outputing an empty array. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For loop revisited actually helped me a ton, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`json_file["attributes"]` is a list so you can't access it like a dictionary.

Try this:

```
for single_file in files:
  with open(single_file, 'r') as f:

    try:
      json_file = json.load(f)
      attrs = json_file["attributes"]
      has_grape_city = any(attr["value"] == "GrapeCity" for attr in attrs)
      if has_grape_city: 
        data.append(single_file)
    except KeyError:
      print(f'Skipping {single_file}')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks like it should work. However, I am getting the type error again.

attrs = json_file["attributes"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: If I add an integer to represent the list indices, it skips every file and returns an empty array(list).

Comment: I think you are loading files that are not json files. Try changing your glob to this: `glob.glob('$./Assets/json/*.json', recursive=True)`. Then you only get files that have the `.json` suffix.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work like this. But I did figure out essentially what I wanted to know by targeting the integer value of a specific letter in the attributes value, in this case the p in grapeCity, and then just using a conditional if statement to see if that index was equal to p (I dont know why but it was making each letter of the word an index of a list.. i guess). Then I printed the length of p's and added them up in excel. Then I looked for a second condition and found there was only 1 duplicate. I am not sure where the duplicate file is, but now I at least know how many there are.